# Kill winword process running more than two minutes

Tags: c#, windows-services

One of my process in service is using Microsoft interop dll to start winword process and create one document. Due to some unknown issue the process does not exits (happens very rarely) due to which all winword process instantiating after that get stuck.

I want to right one service utility which will check for any winword process running for more that 2 mins and kill that process. So that consecutive create statement will run as usual. I would do this in windows service. (C#)

Comment: What happens when your client actually uses word for something other than your application? Do you think he'll like it terminating every 2 minutes?

Comment: You should work on figuring out what the unknown issue is instead

Comment: It instantiate new instance and create word document. Which i suppose doesn't happens if earlier instance is stuck somewhere. I guess earlier process must be waiting for some prompt to be answered like Save/Cancel. Because of which next process doesn't starts.

Comment: It happens very rarely and practically not reproducible. Because of which I am thinking of alternatives.

Comment: The correct alternative is to stop automating Word from an [unsupported application type](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757): "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services)" (Which also outlines some alternatives)

Comment: Damien I will try to find more this... but in current situation where my application is working for more that 2 years now no one would allow me to alter the process.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the commenters that killing Word is not the most elegant solution, but if you are out of alternatives, then this is how you can kill processes with a given name that have been running for more than 2 minutes.

```
// I tested with notepad so you would switch this with the Microsoft Word exe name.
string processName = "notepad";
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

foreach (Process process in processes)
{
    TimeSpan runningTime = DateTime.Now - process.StartTime;
    if (runningTime.TotalMinutes > 2)
        process.Kill();
}
```

Comment: i was trying to do with this approach but winword creates only one instance of winword.exe and If I kill winword.exe it will stops the current operation also if any. Is there any way to find out to kill one document